# Preventing zoom with trigger.io forge

Tags: trigger.io

Is there any way to prevent the application from zooming? My app has this annoying habit of zooming all way in when you focus on a text input (only on Android, using an HTC amaze).

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned - I've tried all of the `<meta>` solutions I could find on the interweb (including this). I'm wondering if there is a native hook for trigger.io that would allow this functionality

Comment: Sorry, I missed this comment: having looked at it more, we disable content zooming at the webview level, so wouldn't expect it to happen at all...
Can you get in touch at support@trigger.io - it would be great to know your Android and device version, and get a copy of your src folder to recreate. Thanks!