# Enable zoom in Trigger.io mobile app

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile, trigger.io

We're developing an app using Trigger.io in conjunction with Jquery Mobile 1.1.1. We're aware of the modifications to the viewport meta tag in JM to enable or disable zoom, but in another Stack question about Trigger.io, one of their devs mentioned they disable zoom at the webview level: [Preventing zoom with trigger.io forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487884/preventing-zoom-with-trigger-io-forge)

We would like to enable zoom when displaying a large image on the page - is this possible using the Trigger framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes we do disable zooming in the WebView: if you include a large, unscaled image in your HTML, the user will be able to scroll around to see the full image, but pinches won't work.

Of course, you could have the image down-scaled to start with, then blow it up to full size when the user clicks on an icon? Libraries such as [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) might help here too.

Also, we would be able to make the WebView's zooming behaviour somewhat configurable (although we would always default to making it non-zoomable). Get in touch with support@trigger.io if you absolutely need different behaviour.

Comment: Thanks James. We'll see if iScroll can help. A zoom icon might be possible, but we were hoping to replicate the default UX, which is usually pinch-to-zoom. The webview configuration is tempting but that sounds like a lot of overhead, so we'll leave it as a last resort. The offer is much appreciated though.